# Rails. Set default timezone when current_user loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'd like to change the application time zone when current_user (Devise) is initialized, like this:

```
    Time.zone = current_user.settings(:main).time_zone
```

What is the best place in the app to put this code at (application controller, before_filter is not a solution)?

Comment: Why ``ApplicationController`` is not a solution? It was going to be my suggestion ...

Comment: Aggree with @dgilperez . `ApplicationController`' `before_filter` is the solution.

Comment: I don't believe that changing app time zone is the right approach. What if user changes timezone? (or it changes itself with daylight saving?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the safest approach here would be to use the **around_action** like such, make sure to specify which action you want this to happen on:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
    around_action :set_time_zone, only: :show

    private

    def set_time_zone
       if current_user
         Time.zone = current_user.settings(:main).time_zone 
       end
       yield         
    end
end
```

Comment: The problem with ApplicationController was that some other controllers didn't have access to current_user (like API controller), but "if current_user" should solve this. :) Thank you so much for advice!